# net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID for spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, keystore

I'm receiving this error on chrome when I try to access a spring boot backend application running on a aws ec2 instance:

> net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

I've already export my certificate to the jre cacerts with:

```
sudo keytool -importcert -file certificate.crt -alias tomcat -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Installed certificate:

```
keytool -list -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -alias tomcat

tomcat, Jan 5, 2021, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 41:41:E0:F6:88:F5:B3:DF:B0:D7:3B:8D:87:95:4B:16:48:C9:92:5D
```

is there somethink else that I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal for **self-signed** certificates. Imagine trying to access an online shop  that has a certificate signed by ... the developer's mom: it should show the warning (*even if we love moms a lot*), because that site isn't secure at all and you shouldn't type your card number there.

That's why there are certificate providers, such as Symantec or [Digicert](https://www.digicert.com/solutions/security-solutions-for-websites), for example. They sign your certificate and anything signed with that is finally identified as a VALID CERT AUTHORITY. *They are like the notaries of online communications*.

For example, click on StackOverflow's page lock on the browser. It will show the provider of this page's certificate, which is [**Let's Encrypt**](https://letsencrypt.org/). This provider allows the creation of trusted certificates without paying a cent, as it's a non-profit  authority run by the [Internet Security Research Group](https://www.abetterinternet.org/).

***Thanks to Voo for pointing this out on the comment side.***

[image]

Comment: You are totally right, was just editing while I read your comment. Deleted the pay a lot of money part

Comment: solved the problem creating a load balancer with an certified: https://henriquesschmitt.medium.com/configurando-roteamento-https-com-aws-load-balancer-de35fa49b25a